# A word for 'one whose diet includes chicken but no other meat'

Tags: single-word-requests

According to MW 'pescatarian' is a noun which means 'one whose diet includes fish but no other meat' and on this subject I posted a question some days ago.

Now I'm searching for a word which means 'one whose diet includes chicken but no other meat'.

Is there anyone who knows that word? If so, please, indicate it.

Comment: I've never known someone who ate a kitchen before.  I suppose "formicavorious" would be an appropriate term.  (Did you perhaps mean "chicken"?)

Comment: *Culinarian* is the word for one who eats kitchens.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider There is no law against you editing your own question!

Comment: it aint that bad a question.. 1+

Comment: @WS2: I would suggest *cuisinarian*. *Culinarian* is one who eats cooking (or perhaps eats cooks).

Comment: How about, "A cluckin' picky-eater"?

Answer (score 5):

From [Food and Nutrition](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2w5i2MBvZf8C&lpg=PA1058&dq=pollotarians&pg=PA1058&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pollotarians&f=false) (Hayes & Laudan, 2008):

> Other, less strict forms of vegetarianism exist, although some critics question whether or not these dietary choices even qualify as vegetarianism. [...] **Pollotarians** do not eat red meat but do eat poultry.

Comment: Hence the fast food chain _El Pollotariano Loco_.

Comment: But they're still tormented by poultrygeists.

Comment: Power to the pollotariat!

Answer (score 1):

[Pollotarian](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-vegetarianism):

> - someone who eats chicken or other poultry, but not meat from mammals, often for environmental, health or food justice reasons.

who follows:

> - **a semi-vegetarian or flexitarian   diet** ,  one that is plant-based with the occasional inclusion of meat products. In 2003, the American Dialect Society voted flexitarian as the year's most useful word and defined it as "a vegetarian who occasionally eats meat".

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple.
I'm a  FF-Vegetarian , if it has feathers or Fins, I might eat it. All other animals are not on my menu.

Answer (score -1):

The usual term is

- **pollo vegetarian**
  (pronounced PO-YO)
  This is usually understood as including eggs.

if they eat eggs but not chicken, it's

- **ovo vegetarian**

if they eat dairy products and eggs, it's

- **lacto-ovo vegetarian** (or ovo-lacto vegetarian)

If they eat fish but no other meat, it's

- **pescetarian** (sometimes called pesco-vegetarian, but some vegetarians object to this term)

And so forth. Combine these prefixes as needed. And if you wish, put a hyphen before "vegetarian" to make a single hyphenated compound, e.g. **lacto-ovo-pollo-pesco-vegetarian** (I was one for 40 years)

Comment: I'll upvote this if you can provide references. I don't expect an authoritative source for the last multi-compound phrase.

Comment: Well, it's in my book: _Ex-Diabetic: Your Guide to Quitting Type 2 Diabetes and Living Without It!  (Xlibris, 2014)_.  But I got most of it from Wikipedia.

Answer (score -1):

A pesco pollo vegetarian avoids red meat but eats chicken and fish. These terms stretch the true definition of a vegetarian, and only the term semi-vegetarian is actually used with much frequency. Lacto ovo vegetarian: A lacto ovo vegetarian diet excludes meat, fish, and poultry but includes dairy products and eggs

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.