# A word for "one who eats peppers"

Tags: single-word-requests, food

I am looking for a word that means a person who eats peppers of any fruit.

For those who don't know what a pepper is, here's the definition, [from Google](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=define%3Apeppers):

> a pungent, hot-tasting powder prepared from dried and ground peppercorns, commonly used as a spice or condiment to flavor food.

Comment: Related: [A word for 'one whose diet includes chicken but no other meat'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237716/a-word-for-one-whose-diet-includes-chicken-but-no-other-meat)

Comment: That's oddly specific. I guess you are stuck with pepper-eater.

Comment: Depends on the context, and if you're going to mention the word pepper or related words around it. If you follow John61's suggestion of "fire eaters" but don't mention chillies or peppers in the surrounding context, you most likely *will be* misunderstood.

Comment: I don't think that definition works as you intend - it's too specific, and doesn't really include, say, bell peppers.

Comment: Why do you want a single word for this? In what context are you going to use it?

Comment: "Peter Piper"..

Comment: If you define someone as a 'pepper-eater' how will you express that they eat other things as well as peppers ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the following New Yorker article there is the slang term ***[fire-eater](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2013/11/04/fire-eaters):***

> - In layman's terms, this means eating a chili that causes one to experience profuse sweating, redness, ...

The term appears also in the following article from [food & wine](http://www.stuff.co.nz/life-style/food-wine/4876411/For-fire-eaters-only-these-chillies-bite-back):

> - For fire eaters only: these chillies bite back